# How to display multiple pictures (png) that are stored locally on Shiny

Tags: r, image, shiny

I tried searching online a lot for a similar question but could not find one that helps with my case. I am very new to Shiny so I hope you all can help me out. Below is a form of the code I have. I am having some trouble pulling some images locally. In the UI you can see in the drop down menu I can select multiple counties and combo them with a reason. In my folder I have many png files titled in this generic format: "CountyX reasonY .png" (there is a space before the file extension).

What I want to do is be able to render multiple pictures in a grid so I can compare the combinations of counties and reason (i.e. see County2 reason1 and County1 reason3 and County2 reason3 and County4 reason2 in a 2x2 grid (or 3x4 if I have 12 etc)). To make it easier, I have uploaded some png files here for experimentation: [PNG 1](https://master.tus.io/files/04f73aced8c3f096222e91a8ee164953), [PNG 2](https://master.tus.io/files/cd619ebe201e073efcedb78d1e4ca662), [PNG 3](https://master.tus.io/files/4078799b27cdf958bf9221ec52f5847a), [PNG 4](https://master.tus.io/files/c1d220195e9ef030361ae5d657e0657d).

The output$plots I have tried only works for displaying one image.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Compare"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(inputId = "countyInput", label = "Filter county",
                  choices = c("County1", "County2", "County3", "County4", "County5"),
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10, `selected-text-format` = "count > 9"),
                  multiple = TRUE),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "reasonInput", label = "Filter reason",
                         choices = c("reason1", "reason2", "reason3"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderImage({
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path("<local path name to png files>", paste(input$countyInput, " ", input$reasonInput, " .png", sep = "")))
    list(src = filename)  
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `grid`, `gridExtra` and `png` you can render the pngs into one "plot".

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(gridExtra)
library(png)
library(grid)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Compare"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(inputId = "countyInput", label = "Filter county",
                  choices = c("County1", "County2", "County3", "County4", "County5"),
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10, `selected-text-format` = "count > 9"),
                  multiple = TRUE),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "reasonInput", label = "Filter reason",
                         choices = c("reason1", "reason2", "reason3"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path("<path>", paste0(input$countyInput, " ", input$reasonInput, ".png", sep = ""))) # you had one extra space before .png
    filename <- filename[file.exists(filename)]
    pngs = lapply(filename, readPNG)
    asGrobs = lapply(pngs, rasterGrob)
    p <- grid.arrange(grobs=asGrobs, nrow = 1)
    }, width = 1000)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You will of course need some error handling for incomplete filenames. Also, you can use `length(filename)` as a condition for `nrow` and `ncol` to get the wanted number of cells in the grid.

Comment: This really helped! Thanks for teaching me about the pngs package. I also learned about the differences between paste0 and paste. Very thankful for your help! P.S. My pngs have an intentional extra space before .png

Comment: Do you have any idea how to resize the images? My images are showing up smaller and it's hard to read. Also will making the images bigger make the window scrollable or cut it off?

Comment: I added `width` to my answer. As https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderPlot.html tells, you can use reactive values to specify the width. So maybe make a reactive expression for the number of images, and use that when specifying `nrow`s and `width`

Comment: And FTR, `width` will make the window scrollable, it won't cut the images.

Comment: Hi annhak, I was working on implementing your suggestions and I ran into another problem. Since you are most familiar with my problem I was hoping you could help me again. My problem is how to do an exception. For example, I choose to display County2 reason1, County2 reason3, and County1 reason3. From these three choices, if I don't have one of the png files for it then none of them will show. If I don't have County2 reason3 then it will give me error that I couldn't find the file and nothing else will show. My goal is to make it so it still displays County2 reason1 and County1 reason3

Comment: I edited my answer with filename <- filename[file.exists(filename)] -line

Comment: hmm this got me closer but I think I could explain my problem better. In my actual case I know I have these files on my computer: County1 reason1, County1 reason2, County1 reason3, County1 reason 4, County2 reason1, County2 reason 4. However when I ask it to select County1&2 reason1&4 I only see County1 reason1 and County2 reason 4 instead of County1 reason1, County1 reason 4, County2 reason1, County2 reason 4 even though I know that these files do exist (as I mentioned above).